# Why does this work? Delete with multiple froms no subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure if this is a bug in SQL Server 2012.

I have a simple query:

```
DELETE 
 FROM TABLE1
 FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 = 1
```

In SSMS, this code parses without errors and deletes the data from `Table1` without errors or warnings. My expectation was that SQL Server would throw an error because of multiple FROM statements without usage of subquery syntax.

Comment: What is your question here? Also, why are you SHOUTING in your title? We can read lowercase letters perfectly fine, thanks.

Comment: @Larnu  I'm guessing the two FROMs  ... A SELECT will fail, but the DELETE does not  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=223361e8096af36bcd9dbfa96e3c312b

Comment: But that, a question does not make, @JohnCappelletti . If the OP is reporting a bug, then they're on the wrong website.

Comment: all good questions

Comment: @Larnu If I came across something like this, my first stop would be SO.  This site is full of questions "Why doesn't this work?"   while this one is "Why DOES this work?" (apologies for the caps) when it clearly shouldn't.

Comment: Documented for [`delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a reference to [FROM clause plus JOIN, APPLY, PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 3):

In the syntax for `DELETE`, the first `FROM` clause specifies which table to delete. The actual keyword `FROM` is optional.

The second `FROM` can be specified if a joined deletion is necessary, so it functions the same as `FROM` in a `SELECT`. In such a query, the first `FROM` then specifies which of the joined tables to delete rows from, as the joined rows are fed through.

However, it is also valid, if somewhat ambiguous, to specify a table in the first `FROM` which is *not* present in the second `FROM`. This effectively causes a cross-join between the two clauses. Without any further `WHERE` clause, it will delete all rows from the table.

In your query, you have

```sql
DELETE 
 FROM TABLE1   -- table to delete rows from
 FROM TABLE2   -- cross-join all these rows
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 = 1   -- filtering
```

So `TABLE2` is cross-joined, and then completely ignored.

---

Normally a joined `DELETE` should look like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM t1   -- should use alias here
FROM TABLE2 t2
JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON some_join_condition  -- normal join
WHERE t1.COL1 = 1   -- other filtering
```