# Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

This question has been moved here and been revised as more logging has been added.

This is the structure of the SQL database:

a) Table called `tblPPObject` which has a `bigint` column called `InsertionID` and this is the PK and there is a clustered index on this column.

b) Table called `tblPPObjectChildObjectList` which has a `bigint` column called `InsertionID` and `bigint` column called `ChildInsertionID`. There is a composite PK on these columns and there is a clustered index on these columns. **There are no FKs on this table**.

d) The database isolation level is `read committed snapshot`.

e) Any procedure that inserts/updates/deletes rows from the tblPPObjectChildObjectList table uses using `(rowlock, updlock)` when accessing rows.

f) All read operations are done in `SNAPSHOT` mode. All write operations are done in `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` mode and so in the database this is effectively `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` as `SNAPSHOT` is switched on. So in the code the transaction is set like this:

```cs
m_sqlTransaction = m_sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(m_readOnly ? IsolationLevel.Snapshot : IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

Periodically, rows are removed from the `tblPPObjectChildObjectList`. These are rows that are no longer part of the list and have not been accessed for 2 mins.

In the procedure that removes these redundant rows, we sometimes get the following error:

```
[2022-01-05 08:27:45.123  TC:08:27:45:01] DEBUG (   87) PP.Workflow.Service.Database.MetadataProvider - Purge failed ('Failed to purge data due to an SQL error ('Error purging items from the database. Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. You cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'dbo.tblPPObjectChildObjectList' directly or indirectly in database 'PPGallium_Metadata' to update, delete, or insert the row that has been mod')').
```

As I mentioned above there are no FKs on this table and I have proved from logging that nothing is changing the rows that are being removed (new rows are being updated and inserted but not the same ones as those being removed).

From my understanding, this means that we should never get the update conflict error.

We are looking for advice/suggestions on how to prevent this error as there is no reason that the remove procedure should raise this exception.

It is worth adding that I have a test system where I can reproduce this issue within one hour consistently.

As requested I have added the create table statements below for the `tblPPObject` table and the `tblPPObjectChildObjectList` table and the purge procedure that is doing the removal.

Please note that there other other tables in the database but the `tblPPObjectChildObjectList` table is the one that is producing the snapshot errors.

Please note that the snapshot error occurs after the 'Removing rows from tblPPObjectChildObjectList' log statement. As you can see a huge amount of logging has been added to make sure that we are not removing rows that are currently being updated.

```sql
-- Parent table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPPObject](
    [ObjectID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [InsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SourceInterpreterID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LevelID] [nvarchar](260) NULL,
    [UpdateID] [bigint] NULL,
    [TypeNameID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SearchParentInsertionID] [bigint] NULL,
    [GroupID] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPPObject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InsertionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPPObject]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblPPObject_tblPPTypeName] FOREIGN KEY([TypeNameID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblPPTypeName] ([TypeNameID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblPPObject] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblPPObject_tblPPTypeName]
GO

-- Child list table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList](
    [SortIndex] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [InsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChildInsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SortText] [nvarchar](260) NULL,
    [UpdateID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RemovalThreshold] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPPObjectChildObjectList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InsertionID] ASC,
    [ChildInsertionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```sql
-- Remove procedure

ALTER procedure [dbo].[spPurge](@modelinsertionid bigint)
as
begin
    
    begin try
        
        print 'Start Purge'

        set deadlock_priority low
        set nocount on

        declare @currenttime datetime
        set @currenttime = GetUTCDate()

        -- It is possible for "redundant" items to come back again due to the service communication so allow for this
        declare @thresholddatetime datetime
        set @thresholddatetime = DATEADD(mi, -2, @currenttime)

        -- Constants
        declare @maximumprocedureruntimeinseconds int
        declare @purgecount int

        declare @objectsremainingtoremove int
        declare @starttime datetime

        set @purgecount = 500
        set @maximumprocedureruntimeinseconds = 1
        set @starttime = @currenttime
        set @objectsremainingtoremove = @purgecount

        -- Create the required temporary tables
        declare @InsertionIDs table (InsertionID bigint, PRIMARY KEY (InsertionID))
        declare @ObjectIDs table (ObjectID uniqueidentifier, PRIMARY KEY (ObjectID))
        declare @RedundantInsertionIDs table (InsertionID bigint, PRIMARY KEY (InsertionID))

        declare @pass int
        set @pass = 0

        while (@objectsremainingtoremove > 0)
        begin

            set @pass = @pass + 1

            delete from @InsertionIDs
            delete from @RedundantInsertionIDs

            -- Get the next set of items to remove from the previous iteration of the procedure. This will be the child rows of the children removed in the previous iteration
            insert into @RedundantInsertionIDs select top (@purgecount) InsertionID from tblPPRedundantObjects
        
            declare @count int
            select @count = count(*) from @RedundantInsertionIDs

            if (@count > 0) 
            begin

                print 'Taken ' + cast(@count as varchar) + ' rows from tblPPRedundantObjects'

            end

            insert into @InsertionIDs select InsertionID from @RedundantInsertionIDs

            set @objectsremainingtoremove = @objectsremainingtoremove - @@rowcount
            if (@objectsremainingtoremove > 0)
            begin

                print 'Get child objects'

                -- Look for entries that have become redundant because the update id has been modified
                insert into @InsertionIDs               
                select top (@objectsremainingtoremove) poco.ChildInsertionID from tblPPObjectChildObject as poco with (rowlock, updlock) 
                where (poco.UpdateID = -1) and (poco.UpdateTime < @thresholddatetime) 

                set @objectsremainingtoremove = @objectsremainingtoremove - @@rowcount
                if (@objectsremainingtoremove > 0)
                begin

                    print 'Get child list objects'

                    -- Look for entries that have become redundant because the update id has been modified
                    insert into @InsertionIDs
                    select top (@objectsremainingtoremove) pocol.ChildInsertionID from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol with (rowlock, updlock) 
                    where (pocol.UpdateID = -1) and (pocol.UpdateTime < @thresholddatetime) 
            
                    set @objectsremainingtoremove = @objectsremainingtoremove - @@rowcount

                end
                
            end

            if ((select count(*) from @InsertionIDs) = 0)
            begin

                break

            end
        
            declare @debug_insertionid int

            DECLARE debug_cursor CURSOR FOR   
            SELECT InsertionID from @InsertionIDs
  
            OPEN debug_cursor  
            FETCH NEXT FROM debug_cursor INTO @debug_insertionid    
  
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN  
  
                PRINT 'InsertionID to remove is ' + cast(@debug_insertionid as varchar(max))

                FETCH NEXT FROM debug_cursor INTO @debug_insertionid  
                
            END  
  
            CLOSE debug_cursor  
            DEALLOCATE debug_cursor

            print 'Get objects'

            insert into @ObjectIDs 
            select ObjectID from tblPPObject as po
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on po.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            print 'Merge in redundant objects 1'

            -- Insert the next level of child items to remove the next time the procedure is called
            merge tblPPRedundantObjects as ro
            using (select ChildInsertionID from tblPPObjectChildObject as poco with (rowlock, updlock) join @InsertionIDs as ii on poco.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID) as s
            on ro.InsertionId = s.ChildInsertionId
            when not matched then 
            insert (InsertionId) values (s.ChildInsertionId);

            print 'Merge in redundant objects 2'

            merge tblPPRedundantObjects as ro
            using (select ChildInsertionID from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol with (rowlock, updlock) join @InsertionIDs as ii on pocol.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID) as s
            on ro.InsertionId = s.ChildInsertionId
            when not matched then 
            insert (InsertionId) values (s.ChildInsertionId);

            print 'Start removing rows...'

            delete from tblPPObjectChildObject with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObject as poco
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on poco.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID
    
            print 'Rows removed from tblPPObjectChildObject is ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(max))

            delete from tblPPObjectChildObjectList with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID
    
            print 'Rows removed from tblPPObjectChildObjectList is ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(max))

            delete from tblPPObjectProperty with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectProperty as op
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on op.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            delete from tblPPObjectBlobProperty with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectBlobProperty as bop
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on bop.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            print 'Removing rows from tblPPObjectChildObject' 

            delete from tblPPObjectChildObject with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObject as poco
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on poco.ChildInsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            print 'Removing rows from tblPPObjectChildObjectList' 
    
            delete from tblPPObjectChildObjectList with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.ChildInsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            print 'Removing rows from tblPPObject' 

            delete from tblPPObject with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObject as po
            join @InsertionIDs as ii
            on po.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            -- Finally we can now remove the objects that we took from the tblRedundantObjects table as they have now been acted upon
            delete from tblPPRedundantObjects
            from tblPPRedundantObjects as ro
            join @RedundantInsertionIDs as ri
            on ro.InsertionID = ri.InsertionID

            print 'Pass processed'

            -- If this procedure has been running too long then stop processing
            if (DATEADD(s, @maximumprocedureruntimeinseconds, @starttime) < GetUtcDate())
            begin

                print 'Stopping due to overrun after ' + cast(@pass as varchar) + ' pass(es) with ' + cast((@purgecount - @objectsremainingtoremove) as varchar) + ' object(s) purged'
                break

            end
            
        end

        print 'End Purge'

        -- Return all the objects that have been removed
        select ObjectID
        from @ObjectIDs
    
    end try
    begin catch

        declare @errormessage varchar(256)
        select @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        -- Raise an error and return
        raiserror('Error purging items from the database. %s', 16, 1, @errormessage)

    end catch
    
end
```

Comment: How long does this procedure take to run? Are any other processes running this at the same time? Can you attach a https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan for the failing statement? `delete from tblPPObjectChildObjectList with (rowlock, updlock) from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol join @InsertionIDs as ii...` is just wrong, you need to use the alias `delete from pocol with (rowlock, updlock) from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol join @InsertionIDs as ii...` also I question why you are using `merge...when not matched` instead of a simple `insert...select...where not exists`.

Comment: is there an idex on [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList]([ChildInsertionID])?

Comment: @Charlieface Can you explain what difference it makes to use the alias in the delete statement? I will look at the merge part of the statement as you suggested.

Comment: @lptr There is an index on the ChildInsertionID. It is:

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblPPObjectChildObjectList_ChildInsertionID_INC_InsertionID_UpdateID_SortText_SortIndex_UpdateTime_RemovalThreshold] ON [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList]
(
 [ChildInsertionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([InsertionID],[UpdateID],[SortText],[SortIndex],[UpdateTime],[RemovalThreshold]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: Otherwise you end up with a cross join of all rows in the table against the two aliased join tables. You probably want an index on `InsertionID`

Comment: @Charlieface The execution plan is identical whether the alias is used or not so I do not see how this could make any difference?

Comment: I was referring to problems like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643735/14868997. Hmm interesting, it seems if the table has already been mentioned then it will use it regardless of the alias, without cross-joining, but it can sometimes be ambiguous. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0351f7c828b81bff22a60b9801db984d