# Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict in SQL Server when removing rows

Tags: sql-server, snapshot-isolation

I now have a simple example of this issue following on from: [Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639803/snapshot-isolation-transaction-aborted-due-to-update-conflict-in-sql-server)

This is the script to create the database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList](
    [SortIndex] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [InsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChildInsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SortText] [nvarchar](260) NULL,
    [UpdateID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RemovalThreshold] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPPObjectChildObjectList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InsertionID] ASC,
    [ChildInsertionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblPPObjectChildObjectList_ChildInsertionID_INC_InsertionID_UpdateID_SortText_SortIndex_UpdateTime_RemovalThreshold] ON [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList]
(
    [ChildInsertionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([InsertionID],[UpdateID],[SortText],[SortIndex],[UpdateTime],[RemovalThreshold]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblPPObjectChildObjectList_InsertionID_UpdateID_INC_SortText_SortIndex_UpdateTime_RemovalThreshold] ON [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList]
(
    [InsertionID] ASC,
    [UpdateID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([SortText],[SortIndex],[UpdateTime],[RemovalThreshold]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtPPChildObjectList] AS TABLE(
    [InsertionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChildInsertionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SortIndex] [int] NULL,
    [UpdateId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SortText] [nvarchar](260) NULL,
    [RemovalThreshold] [bigint] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChildInsertionId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtPPInsertionIDList] AS TABLE(
    [InsertionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InsertionID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Snapshot isolation must be on in the database and read committed snapshot must be on.

This script should be used to populate the table:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1

while (@i < 200)
begin

    insert into [dbo].[tblPPObjectChildObjectList]
    select -1, GetUTCDate(), @i, @i * 1000, null, 1, null

    set @i = @i + 1

end
GO
```

There are then two scripts which must be run at the same time. This is the update script:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO 

declare @insertionid bigint
set @insertionid = 1

while (1 = 1)
begin

    BEGIN TRY
     
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

        declare @updatetime datetime
        set @updatetime = GetUTCDate()

        declare @values dbo.udtPPChildObjectList
        delete from @values

        insert into @values select 1, 1000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 2, 2000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 3, 3000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 4, 4000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 5, 5000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 6, 6000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 7, 7000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 8, 8000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 9, 9000, -1, 1, null, null
        insert into @values select 10, 10000, -1, 1, null, null
                    
        update t 
        set t.UpdateTime = @updatetime
        from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as t 
        join @values as s
        on s.ChildInsertionId = t.ChildInsertionID

        select t.ChildInsertionID
        from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as t with (updlock, rowlock) 
        left join @values as s
        on s.InsertionId = t.InsertionID and s.ChildInsertionId = t.ChildInsertionID
        where (t.InsertionID in (select InsertionId from @values)) and (s.ChildInsertionId is null)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION; 

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        print 'ERROR :' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        break;

    END CATCH

end 
GO
```

and this is the delete script:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
GO  

while (1 = 1)
begin

    BEGIN TRY

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

        declare @insertionids dbo.udtPPInsertionIDList

        declare @i int
        set @i = 1

        while (@i < 150)
        begin

            insert into @insertionids
            select 90000000 + @i

            set @i = @i + 1

        end

        set deadlock_priority low
        set nocount on

        -- Create the required temporary tables
        declare @LocalInsertionIDs table (InsertionID bigint, PRIMARY KEY (InsertionID))
        
        delete from @LocalInsertionIDs
        insert into @LocalInsertionIDs 
        select InsertionID from @insertionids

        if ((select count(*) from @LocalInsertionIDs) > 0)
        begin
        
            declare @c4 int
            select @c4 = count(*) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol
            join @LocalInsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            delete from pocol with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol with (rowlock, updlock) 
            join @LocalInsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.InsertionID = ii.InsertionID
            
            declare @c5 int
            select @c5 = count(*) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol
            join @LocalInsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.ChildInsertionID = ii.InsertionID

            delete from pocol with (rowlock, updlock) 
            from tblPPObjectChildObjectList as pocol with (rowlock, updlock) 
            join @LocalInsertionIDs as ii
            on pocol.ChildInsertionID = ii.InsertionID

        end

        delete from @insertionids

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        
        print 'ERROR :' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        break;

    END CATCH

end
GO
```

After 10-15 minutes the delete script will fail with the update error even though the rows being removed are not being updated (in fact they do not even exist).

Can anyone see why this exception is being raised?

Answer (score 0):

> After 10-15 minutes the delete script will fail with the update error
> even though the rows being removed are not being inserted or updated.

The query below to get the rows to be deleted performs a full scan of the `tblPPObjectBlobProperty` table because no index exists on `UpdateTime`. The `UPDLOCK` lock will fail when rows outside the range to be deleted are accessed and the row has been modified by another transaction.

```
    insert into @InsertionIDs               
    select distinct InsertionID, UpdateTime from tblPPObjectBlobProperty as poco with (rowlock, updlock) 
    where UpdateTime < @thresholddatetime
```

Add an index on the `UpdateTime` column so that only the rows to be deleted are touched. This should avoid the update conflict error.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tblPPObjectBlobProperty_UpdateTime ON dbo.tblPPObjectBlobProperty(UpdateTime);
```

On a side note, I suggest you use `THROW` to facilitate troubleshooting. The error message will include the line number of the problem statement in the script. Also, add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to scripts/procs with explicit transactions to ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately after an error, client timeout, or query cancel. Below is the standard catch block I use.

```
BEGIN CATCH 

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Comment: Just curious: what's the point of a `CATCH` block if all it does is rollback? `XACT_ABORT ON` would have sorted that out anyway

Comment: @Charlieface, `XACT_ABORT_ON` is probably enough to do the job here but I always include a conditional rollback and `THROW` in production code for the reasons Erland details in his [error handling series](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern).  Consider devs often copy/paste catch block code without considering the full context and this one will work regardless of the `XACT_ABORT` setting.

Comment: This is only a test script and the exception handling is not a concern at the moment. I have modified the example so that all the indexes required to stop table scans are in there and this still produces the same error.

Comment: @Sputnik, I was able to repro your issue before the index but not after creating the index. Can you review your actual execution plans?

Comment: @DanGuzman Please note that I have changed the database and scripts above. The index did fix the issue on the previous example but the above example causes the issue and there are no indexes to add.

Comment: @Sputnik. I get errors with your new scripts because the dbo.udtPPChildObjectList type is missing.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added the types to the main creation script in the question.

Comment: @Sputnik, the latest execution plans show merge joins using non-clustered index scans. This cause the snapshot error when rows not to be deleted are accessed with the `UPDLOCK` hint. The simple solution is to remove the hints.

Comment: @DanGuzman Not sure I follow - can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Sputnik, the merge join operators in [the delete query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r16nZm_6t) perform full ordered scans of the non-clustered indexes, touching every row in the table. Even when a row will not be deleted (not in `@LocalInsertionIDs`), your `UPDLOCK` hint specifies an update intent which results in the error when the row was modified by another transaction. I see no need for the `UPDLOCK` hint here since the actual rows to be deleted won't be modified. SQL Server will then acquire restrictive locks on only the rows deleted.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for your input - that made a big difference but there are still issus occurring in our main database (the above was an example). I have opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70802876/snapshot-isolation-transaction-aborted-due-to-update-conflict-in-sql-server-due